# Is this a stock Android Notification (RemoteView) layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

On my HTC phone the RemoteView for notifications looks like the image below...

[image]

I'd like to use the same layout (image, bold text and small text) for a notification in my app but I can't work out if it's a stock Android layout or not. I've created my own layout but it's not quite the same and I'd like to stick to the 'standard' if possible.

Using eclipse I tried typing in `android.R.layout.` to see what the suggestions were but I can't see any with a name which would suggest a notification layout.

Is it a stock Android layout? If so, how do I access it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is standard Android notification layout and you don't need to create your own custom layout. Just use existing notification API to set drawable, title and text. Below is an example, using `NotificationCompat.Builder` from compatibility library:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityHome.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setTicker(getText(R.string.notification_ticker))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
        .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_text));

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```

And the same using `Notification` class:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, getText(R.string.notification_ticker), System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityHome.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notification_title), getText(R.string.notification_text), pendingIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```